# Insert sequential numbers into Oracle PL/SQL database

Tags: for-loop, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to insert a sequence of numbers into a DB. This is my code but its not working:

```
DECLARE 
  j number(10) ;
BEGIN
  FOR j IN 1001020930..1001021930
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO PROD.issue_id(j,'NEW',null)
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Table structure:

```
VARCHAR2 (128 BYTE)
VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE)
DATE
```

This is the error code:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE 
  j number(10) ;
BEGIN
  FOR j IN 1001020930..1001021930
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO PROD.issue_id(j,'NEW',null)
  END LOOP;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 42:
PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   loop
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I don't understand these errors because I am very new to PL/SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `values` command  in your insert statement and not terminated insert statement with a semicolon.

Do as

```
    DECLARE
    j    NUMBER (10);
BEGIN
    FOR j IN 1001020930 .. 1001021930
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO   issue_id
              VALUES   (j, 'NEW', SYSDATE);
    END LOOP;
END;
```